# Required request parameter 'image' for method parameter type String is not present

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

I have a problem with spring http method

```
    @PutMapping("/book/photo/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updatePhoto(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestParam("image") String image)
    {
        try
        {
            bookService.updateImage(id,null);
        }
        catch (BadRequestIdException e)
        {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(e.getMessage());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("PHOTO WAS UPDATED");
    }
```

[image]

When I run this in postman I get response

```
2021-07-09 12:17:52.768  WARN 2860 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved 
[org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: 
Required request parameter 'image' for method parameter type String is not present]
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: can you see me your url with request Param

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you posted binary data to a controller that takes a String. If that isn't the case then this error can also be cause by the controller receiving a partial payload due to timeout or network loss.